# How to watch communication between 2 processes?

Tags: ida, dynamic-analysis

I have exe file in my pc(exe1) that send message to another exe (client-server maybe).

I dont know which exe recived this message from exe1 and with which iso that message encoding.

1. How can I see which exe recived message from exe1.
2. How can I see with which ISO this message encoding?

Comment: what is "ISO"? also please fix "witch" to "which"

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky there are a variety of ways how to encode message between 2 processes (how to encode each 8 bits). For ex. if yiu encode each 8 bits with ASCII ,because ASCII is only 7 bits, you lose the msb bits of each byte

Comment: why do you think one exe is sending messages to another? please add more information to the question

Comment: For ex. in exe1 there is user login (put user and password) and exe2 add this user and password to database,  exe1 don't have a access to db

Comment: Do you know if the message sent is via a proprietary API or Windows API? If the latter, then perhaps an application like API Monitor might be of help: http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor

Comment: @dsasmblr thank you,  I not dind there how to monitor spesific process,  and if this process can be turn on when I start to monitor it?  Thank

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways two processes can communicate. The general term for this is IPC (Interprocess Communications). On Windows, the following [forms of IPC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications) are commonly used:

- COM
- Window messages (simple messages for small data amounts, `WM_COPYDATA` for bigger amounts)
- File mapping, or named shared memory
- Shared memory
- Pipes (named or anonymous)
- Sockets (e.g. TCP/IP)
- passing info via command-line arguments (though this is not really IPC)

Less common but still possible:

- Clipboard
- Mailslots
- RPC (remote procedure call)

Which one is actually used is difficult to say with limited information you provided. Using an API monitor, as suggested by @dsasmblr may give you some hints. You can also just debug or RE the executable which processes user input and see what is being done with the entered information.

Comment: I didn't success watch the communication at `api monitor` but I saw the message was sent when exe1 call to `ObjectStublessClientXX` in ole32.dll  is that explain something? Is that passable?

Comment: This smells like COM(or, less likely, RPC). Unfortunately there’s too little space in the answering box for introduction into COM

Comment: Is there any way to verify that is com? Why do you think that COM when I tell `ObjectStublessClientXX`??

Comment: @Keystone "stub" and "client" is OLE/COM terminology: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Midl/c-compiler-definitions-for-proxy-stubs

Comment: So when I saw `ObjectStublessClientXX` that mean communication between process? How can I see what is the message that send between process and to which process my process send that message??   Thank